# HoloToolkit Spatial Understanding Raycast Customization to work fast for indicating gaze points on an augmented dense vertices 3D model

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting, hololens

I need some help figuring out the Spatial Understanding (Playspace)Raycast which is part of the HoloToolkit (now also known as [MixedRealityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit/blob/ff2b02d500a504bf3a0812a5548b64d1dcfc542e/SpatialUnderstanding/Src/PlaySpace/PlaySpaceInfos_W.cpp)) and if it possible to make it work with a more detailed mesh of a custom generated/loaded object (just to make it capable of interactively selecting via gaze the individual surfels not actually doing the spatial understanding)?

As I understand the Raycast method in question works with 8x8x8cm voxels (and surface elements belonging to those aka surfels) so I'd like to try and load a 3D model with a sub-1cm precision and have it work on that model showing the gaze cursor's position on the models surface interactively...or could it be even done somehow in Unity 3D in C# via some box-like colliders directly...having tried to do it with a model with about 80k vertices it seems not to be interactive at all on a HL1 device.

What I'd like to know is could it be made to work on that HoloLens device (given limited CPU) with some extra optimization maybe and if you have some ideas how, or if and how could I further that (Playcast)Raycast (since I gather it's been written in C++ and is being used in Unity by marshaling the native dll, I'm guessing it's faster than rewriting it to work directly in Unity 3D and C#, or am I wrong and it's actually fast just because of the large voxel/surfel sizes and/or some other optimizations - maybe it's not scanning all the surfels but just some - I only don't get how does it do that then...shouldn't it be working with all surfels regardless...doesn't raycast generally does that)?

Anyways, thanks for any insight, I'm new to Unity/HoloLens so sorry if I'm not describing/understanding the problem yet...I'll be sure to update if I get more understanding...TIA

Comment: I am not sure you understand the point of the HoloToolkit. Those methods are there to interact with the real world. If you want to raycast against your own model, you can use the regular raycast methods. The user's gaze is always in the center of the main camera.

Comment: But if the regular (mesh) raycast seems to be slowing down the interactivity of the app on the HL1, then the question stays valid (albeit slightly changed - I'll update it a bit - thank you for that), how to make a raycast (and basing it on the HoloToolkit's PlayspaceRaycast seems like a solid starting point to me) that will work with as many as few hundred thousand triangle surfaces on a HL1 device (do you need to go the C++ route and have it be marshalled to work fast enough or are there some mash collider optimizations I'm missing)…thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Hopefully the edit is making it a bit more clear and if not please suggest changes and I'll edit more...so the problem is that since the user's gaze is in the center of the main camera I just can't draw a line to indicate what I'm about to select as that gets uncomfortable to look at, but the gaze cursor then needs some raycast capable of working with a large number of trinagles in near-realtime to be updating as fast as the user's gaze can move, and that's where I'm getting stuck for now...or am I missing something?

Comment: The "large number of triangles" is the issue. The playspace volumetric mesh is not actually that large, and having worked with the device I can say with some degree of certainty that the method your talking about is not in some way more efficient than a standard raycast. Its just set up to do that raycast against a specific (run-time defined, dynamic) mesh.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, so in esence then, I'm basically screwed? Say then, hypothetically, I want models that are precise, are there any other options for me? I was thinking maybe a raycast method that "framed" out most of the triangles could work but can you even do it that way (what would be the excluding frame size if the model is placed far away from the viewer - most would be in frame)...maybe I should make a new question...or are there any resources on making optimized raycasts for mash colliders out there to read and inform myself more before making such question please? Thanks again.

Comment: Mesh collider performance is terrible in general, all around.